# Output increasing every time the command is used

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I tried to make a kick members script in discord.js. My error is, that every time I send the !kick command the message gets displayed one more time. For example, if I send !kick for the first time, it would send this response: "Please specify a user!". If I send it for the second time, it would send that message twice, and so on. My code:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js")

exports.run = async(client, msg, args) => {
    msg.delete();
    if(!msg.member.hasPermission('KICK_MEMBERS')) return msg.reply('you don\'t have permission to use this command!')


    const user = msg.mentions.users.first() || msg.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]);
    if(!user) return msg.reply(`please specify a user you wish to be punished.`).then(msg => msg.delete({timeout: 5000}));

    let member;
    try {
        member = await msg.guild.members.fetch(user)
    } catch(err) {
        member = null;
    }
    if(member){
        if(member.hasPermission('MANAGE_MESSAGES')) return msg.reply('that user is too cool to be banned.').then(msg => msg.delete({timeout: 5000}));
    }

    let reason = args.slice(1).join(' ');
    if(!reason) return msg.reply('please specify a reason.').then(msg => msg.delete({timeout: 5000}));

    let channel = msg.guild.channels.cache.find(c => name.name === '┊discord_logs');

    let log = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#0088FF')
    .setDescription(`${user} has been kicked by ${msg.author} for ${reason}`)
    channel.send(log);

    let userLog = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#0088FF')
    .setDescription(`You have been kicked from Scratta for: ${reason}`)
    try {
        await user.send(userLog);
    } catch(err) {
        console.warn(err);
    }
    member.kick(reason)

    let confir = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#0088FF')
    .setDescription(`${user} has been kicked from Scratta.`)
    msg.channel.send(confir);
    
    msg.delete();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You‘re missing this line at the top in your `module.exports`:

```js
if (msg.author.bot) return;
```

This will make sure that the bot doesn‘t react to his own message

Comment: I am so dumb. That fixed it, thank you very much! I don't know how I managed to forget something that simple.

Comment: Glad I could help :) Would be nice if you‘d mark the answer as accepted

Comment: i am new to stackoverflow, how do i mark it?